# Changing tintColor of UISearchBar inside ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, tintcolor

I am tyring to customize the colors a bit in a `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` below is my complete code:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *objPeoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[objPeoplePicker setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
objPeoplePicker.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.294 green:0.278 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];
objPeoplePicker.topViewController.searchDisplayController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.294 green:0.278 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];
[self presentModalViewController:objPeoplePicker animated:YES];
```

Customizing the NavigationBar tintColor, this line works:

```
objPeoplePicker.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.294 green:0.278 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];
```

But, I'd also like to customize the tintColor of the searchBar:

```
objPeoplePicker.topViewController.searchDisplayController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.294 green:0.278 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];
```

That line does not work. I think I may be referencing the wrong searchBar....can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. Changing the navBar color is easy. Changing the UISearchBar color however not so much.  First what I did was to check

```
if( picker.searchDisplayController == nil ) 
  NSLog(@"searchDisplayController is nil");
if( picker.topViewController.searchDisplayController == nil ) 
  NSLog(@"topViewController.searchDisplayController is nil");
```

Both times the searchDisplayController was nil.  What I ended up doing was traversing the view hierarchy to find the UISearchBar view.  There is certainly one there right.  So this is my final code. If anyone has a better solution I would love to hear it.

```
static BOOL foundSearchBar = NO;
- (void)findSearchBar:(UIView*)parent mark:(NSString*)mark {

  for( UIView* v in [parent subviews] ) {

    if( foundSearchBar ) return;

    NSLog(@"%@%@",mark,NSStringFromClass([v class]));

    if( [v isKindOfClass:[UISearchBar class]] ) {
      [(UISearchBar*)v  setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
      foundSearchBar = YES;
      break;
    }
    [self findSearchBar:v mark:[mark stringByAppendingString:@"> "]];
  }
}

- (void)pickPerson:(BOOL)animated {
  foundSearchBar = NO;
  ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
  [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

  picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
  picker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                  nil];

  [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:animated];
  [picker release];

  [self findSearchBar:[picker view] mark:@"> "];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, even though this thread is way old, it may be of use to me later on. 'Preciate the time!

Comment: One thing I noticed afterwards was that if hit Groups on the top left of the Picker and then return to contacts the search bar color changes to the default grey.

Comment: I think "picker release" comes a little too early in this code, as you use "picker" in the following line.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the color I add an image to the background:

```
[mysearchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"<#Your image name#>"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the UISearchBar appearance proxy now:

```
UISearchBar* addressBookSearchBar = [UISearchBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil];
addressBookSearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

For iOS7+ the easiest way is manipulating the appearance proxy of the `UISearchBar`:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```