# How can I change color of UINavigationBar of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abpeoplepickerview

I'm using `ABAddressBookRef` to get information of people for my Phone book. It works properly, but I want to change color of `UINavigationBar` of `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`.

Is this possible or not? If possible, please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the tint color , like this way....

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *objPeoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[objPeoplePicker setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
objPeoplePicker.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.294 green:0.278 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];
[self presentModalViewController:objPeoplePicker animated:YES];
```

**Changing the UISearchBar color**

```
if( picker.searchDisplayController == nil ) 
  NSLog(@"searchDisplayController is nil");
if( picker.topViewController.searchDisplayController == nil ) 
  NSLog(@"topViewController.searchDisplayController is nil");


static BOOL foundSearchBar = NO;
- (void)findSearchBar:(UIView*)parent mark:(NSString*)mark {

  for( UIView* v in [parent subviews] ) {

    if( foundSearchBar ) return;

    NSLog(@"%@%@",mark,NSStringFromClass([v class]));

    if( [v isKindOfClass:[UISearchBar class]] ) {
      [(UISearchBar*)v  setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
      foundSearchBar = YES;
      break;
    }
    [self findSearchBar:v mark:[mark stringByAppendingString:@"> "]];
  }
}

- (void)pickPerson:(BOOL)animated {
  foundSearchBar = NO;
  ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
  [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

  picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
  picker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                  nil];

  [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:animated];
  [picker release];

  [self findSearchBar:[picker view] mark:@"> "];
}
```

Comment: @vikash - thaks for help me :) i wn as change color of UISearchBar of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ... how can i do it ?

Comment: Doesn't change the tint color in iOS 8 for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use appearance proxies to govern the appearance of the nav bar in the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` like so:

for a red bar with white bar button items:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to change `UINavigationBar` Color

```
    abPeoplePicker.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: thanks for help me :) ...i wn as change color of UISearchBar of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ... how can i do it ?

Comment: Go to this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618976/changing-tintcolor-of-uisearchbar-inside-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) {
    UIImage *backGroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:kNavigationBarBackGroundImage] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:5];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:backGroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

This will affect all navigation bars but you set a backgroudn image rather then setting the background image but settintcolor sets only sets the color of the bars

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to change **ABPeoplePickerNavigationController** Color

```
objPicker.ViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

or you can set **RGB** color

```
  objPicker.ViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.274 green:0.270 blue:0.268 alpha:0.8];
```

Comment: thanks for help me :) ...i wn as change color of UISearchBar of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController ... how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

change color of **UISearchBar** of **ABPeoplePickerNavigationController** 
use  like this way....

```
objPicker.ViewController.searchDisplayController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.294 green:0.278 blue:0.247 alpha:1.0];
```

[Changing tintColor of UISearchBar inside ABPeoplePickerNavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618976/changing-tintcolor-of-uisearchbar-inside-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller)

Comment: @AmitPatel hope u help full otherwise i will try this code and talk u later....:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static BOOL foundSearchBar = NO;
- (void)findSearchBar:(UIView*)parent mark:(NSString*)mark {

  for( UIView* v in [ subviews] ) {

    if( foundSearchBar ) return;

    NSLog(@"%@%@",mark,NSStringFromClass([v class]));

    if( [v isKindOfClass:[UISearchBar class]] ) {
      [(UISearchBar*)v  setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
      foundSearchBar = YES;
      break;
    }
    [self findSearchBar:v mark:[mark stringByAppendingString:@"> "]];
  }
}

- (void)pickPerson:(BOOL)animated {
  foundSearchBar = NO;
  ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
  [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

  picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
  picker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                  nil];

  [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:animated];
  [picker release];

  [self findSearchBar:[picker view] mark:@"  "];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
picker.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
```